# Set of records with non existing nested field or conditiontional existance of a nested field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying to get a set of `product` documents where there is no `"product_text.language_id": 1` record in `product_texts` object **OR** `product_texts` with an empty `product_texts.description` field with `"product_text.language_id": 1`. `product_texts` is the sub-document of products index.

I tried this below query but it returns some `product`s with existing `product_texts.description`.

```
"bool": {
  "must": [
    {
      "nested": {
        "path": "product_texts",
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "product_texts.language_id": 1
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "product_texts.description"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "term": {
                              "product_texts.language_id": 1
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the `product` mapping;

```
properties: {
    id: {
      type: 'long',
    },
...
product_texts: {
  type: 'nested',
  properties: {
    description: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256,
        },
      },
    },
    id: {
      type: 'long',
    },
    language_id: {
      type: 'long',
    },
    name: {
      type: 'text',
      fields: {
        keyword: {
          type: 'keyword',
          ignore_above: 256,
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Example complate set:

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "products",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "131483",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "product_texts": [
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 1
          },
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 2
          },
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "products",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "131484",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "product_texts": [
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 2
          },
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    },    {
      "_index": "products",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "131485",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "product_texts": [
          {
            "description": null,
            "language_id": 1
          },
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 2
          },
          {
            "description": "Some description",
            "language_id": 3
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected query result _ids 131484 and 131485, **NOT** 131483 because it has a record in product_texts with a not-null description and language_id 1.

Comment: can u add a sample doc which is part of the result but shouldn't be?

Comment: Are you saying that docs with description whose lang id is other than 1? - `I tried this below query but it returns some products with existing product_texts.description.`, then palm is with your second `must_not` part

Comment: @Gibbs here you go

Comment: I got records with not empty descriptions with language_id 1

Comment: I got it. You are getting because other records in that array has met your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does the job

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [ /** OR condition **/
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "product_texts",
            "query": {
              "bool": { /** No change in the first condition **/
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "term": {
                            "product_texts.language_id": 1
                          }
                        }
                      ],
                      "must_not": [
                        {
                          "exists": {
                            "field": "product_texts.description"
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": { /** Negated the existence query with value - None of the nested array matches - that's where the real problem**/
            "must_not": { /**Negating the logic **/
              "nested": {
                "path": "product_texts",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": {
                      "term": {/**lang id 1 is present **/
                        "product_texts.language_id": 1
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Please find the comments.

So your second condition: `key with value` should not be present.